# Is Object(argument) a function? what does it return?

Tags: javascript

The following code is used to check variable type and filter array

```
const filter = (predicate, xs) => xs.filter(predicate)
const is = (type) => (x) => Object(x) instanceof type
filter(is(Number), [0, '1', 2, null]) // [0, 2]
```

Q1: I don't understand what the usage of Object(...), what does it return? if I directly use x, the code doesn't work

```
const filter = (predicate, xs) => xs.filter(predicate);
const is = (type) => (x) => x instanceof type;
filter(is(Object), [0, '1', 2, null]) // [];
```

Q2: the value returned by Object(...) is instance of Object and Number/String, why is that?

```
Object('1') instanceof String && Object('1') instanceof Object;//true
Object(2) instanceof Number && Object(2) instanceof Object;//true
typeof Object(2) //"object"
```

It really confuses me a lot, thanks for your support!

[the code source](https://github.com/hemanth/functional-programming-jargon/blob/master/readme.md#higher-order-functions-hof)

Comment: I can't easily type a full explanation now (on my phone), but I'm certain the first code snippet can be implemented more simply with the `typeof` operator. (The short answer to your question though is that `Number` and so on are JS's "native constructors", and if you convert a primitive type to an object you get something which is both an object and an instance of the relevant native.)